# Как запретить работу курсора в определенном приложении?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, windows-10, chrome-extension, курсор

Я играю в GeForce Now (приложение на компьютере, не в окне браузера) и на фоне смотрю сериалы в маленьком окне в углу экрана с помощью расширения Picture-in-picture Chome. Когда курсор попадает в область окна и я кликаю в этот момент, то окно активируется, плеер ставится на паузу, я теряю контроль над GeForce Now и полностью переключаюсь на окно расширения.
Как мне запретить курсору работать в хроме, или расширении хрома в то время пока я играю в GeForce Now?

Comment: Да, Windows 10.

Comment: Значит ставьте вопросу соответствующую метку ;-)